# Slow solving with ECOS_BB, CBC errors with "Not enough constraints"

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I have an binary MIP optimization problem where I want to select the best candidates given a budget and constraints on some other attributes. For each candidate I have a sample vector of their possible utilities obtained from a separate bayesian analysis. There are correlations between the candidates. So rather than selecting the best candidates based just on their mean utility I want to negatively weight candidate pairs that are too correlated. Somewhat similar to a mean-variance optimization portfolio in finance.

Code is below with toy example data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cvxpy as cvx

N = 256
N_SAMPLES = 2**10
N_AGENCIES = 16

static_data = {'style':np.random.randint(4, size=N), 'agency':np.random.randint(N_AGENCIES, size=N), 'hourly_rate':np.random.normal(160, 32, size=N).astype(np.int)}
df = pd.DataFrame(static_data)
#df.head()

S = np.random.randn(N,N)
cov = S.dot(S.T)
cov = np.divide(np.divide(cov, np.sqrt(np.diag(cov).reshape(-1,1))), np.sqrt(np.diag(cov).reshape(1,-1)))
mu = static_data['hourly_rate']
mu = (mu - mu.mean())/mu.std()
samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=N_SAMPLES)
#samples.shape


HOURLY_BUDGET = 1000
REQUIRED_STYLES = np.array([3, 2, 1, 4])
MAX_PER_AGENCY = 2
M_AGENCIES = np.eye(N_AGENCIES)[df['agency']].astype(np.int)
M_STYLES = np.eye(4)[df['style']].astype(np.int)

### Optimization in cvxPy
selection = cvx.Variable(N, boolean=True)
utility = samples@selection
total_utility = cvx.sum(utility)
avg_utility = total_utility / utility.size
utility_over_avg = utility - avg_utility
risk = cvx.norm(utility_over_avg, 2)

constraint_number = cvx.sum(selection)==np.sum(REQUIRED_STYLES)
constraint_styles = selection@M_STYLES == REQUIRED_STYLES
constraint_agencies = cvx.max( selection@M_AGENCIES ) <= MAX_PER_AGENCY
constraint_budget = cvx.sum( selection*df['hourly_rate'].values ) <= HOURLY_BUDGET
constraints = [constraint_number, constraint_styles, constraint_agencies, constraint_budget]

alpha_value = 0.01
alpha = cvx.Parameter(pos=True, value=alpha_value)
prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Maximize(total_utility - risk*alpha), constraints=constraints)

prob.solve(solver='ECOS_BB')
print( 'solverName', prob.solver_stats.solver_name )
print( 'solverStatus', prob.status )

selected_flags = selection.value.round().astype(np.bool)
print( selected_flags.dot(M_STYLES).astype(np.int), selected_flags.dot(M_AGENCIES).max(), selected_flags.dot(df['hourly_rate']) )
print( df.loc[selected_flags] )
```

This works in cvxpy and I get a solution. However as I increase alpha_value to a higher number to penalize correlations more then ECOS_BB takes a long time. In my real code it is taking >24hrs to either solve or to come back with infeasible. Lower values of alpha_value solve within 2-5mins in the real code. The real data has 8000 samples, around 150 candidates, and the same setup of constraints.

If I try with solver='CBC' then it fails immediately with error message

```
SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['CBC']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.
```

A few questions:

- Is CBC better than ECOS_BB in general?
- Is there another free solver
  that I can use that might be better suited?
- Can I reformulate the
  problem such that CBC will work? It works fine if I remove the risk
  and just optimize for the mean utility.
- Can I reformulate to make
  ECOS_BB quicker?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your individual questions.

- **Is CBC better than ECOS_BB in general?** Yes, ECOS_BB is only meant for very small toy problems. CBC is much more advanced when it comes to linear MIP models. However your model is not linear, so CBC is not the right solver for your problem. You are trying to solve a MISOCP/MIQP problem.
- **Is there another free solver that I can use that might be better suited?** Depends. If you are an academic, you can use Cplex or Gurobi for free. If you are not an academic these solvers are expensive. I am not aware of open source MISOCP/MIQP solvers besides ECOS_BB. There are open source MINLP solvers that can solve MIQPs (however these are not supported by CVXPY).
- **Can I reformulate the problem such that CBC will work? It works fine if I remove the risk and just optimize for the mean utility.** (1) May be, but not so easy. It may be possible to write down the KKT conditions and form a MIP. May be a cutting plane strategy could work. Furthermore, it may be possible to linearize things as we are optimizing over binary variables (`x'Qx` can be linearized if `x` is binary). Anyway: this all requires some work, and may not be worth the effort. (2) Yes, if you remove risk, the model becomes linear. CBC can solve this linear model.
- **Can I reformulate to make ECOS_BB quicker?** Not that I am aware of. Again, ECOS_BB is not a strong solver. It may be good enough for proof-of-concept models (of course that is valuable in itself), but for any real work, I would look at other solvers.